# chrome extension passing multiple message to external site by sharing local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, postmessage

**

> RESOLVED

**

I'm developing a chrome extension. reading on stackoverflow I was able to share the local storage between different domains and to send a data from the extension to my external site.

what I would like to do, however, is to send more than one message to the external site. how can i adapt the code i am using? i am not very familiar with js, sorry

**This is the code on popup.html -> extension (function perfectly)**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var receiver = document.getElementById('receiver').contentWindow;

    var btn = document.getElementById('send');

    function sendMessage(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

        receiver.postMessage(document.getElementById('D1').value, 'http://externalsite');

    }

    btn.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
}
```

**This is the code on external site -> receiver**

```
window.onload=function(){ var messageEle=document.getElementById('message');

window.addEventListener('message',receiveMessage);
function receiveMessage(e){
    if(e.origin!=="chrome-extension://ldjfmalmmomhpjmoeemlaingagdhagjl")
    return;
    messageEle.value = e.data;
}
}
```

**What i need is send more of**

```
   receiver.postMessage(document.getElementById('D1').value, 'http://externalsite');
```

**for example**

```
receiver.postMessage(document.getElementById('D1').value, 'http://externalsite');
receiver.postMessage(document.getElementById('D2').value, 'http://externalsite');
receiver.postMessage(document.getElementById('D3').value, 'http://externalsite');
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Send objects like `{id: 'D1', value: document.getElementById('D1').value}`

Comment: thanks for response, can you give me an example with my code?

Answer (score 1):

**for helping other, i resolve in this mode**

in popup.html code on extension

```
window.onload = function() {
    var receiver = document.getElementById('receiver').contentWindow;
    var data = {
        domanda1: (document.getElementById('D1').value),
        domanda2: (document.getElementById('D2').value),
        domanda3: (document.getElementById('D3').value)
};

    var btn = document.getElementById('send');

    function sendMessage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        receiver.postMessage(data, 'externaldomain');

    }

    btn.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
}
```

and in the receiver page -external site- with code

```
window.onload=function(){
    var domanda1=document.getElementById('domanda1');
    var domanda2=document.getElementById('domanda2');
    var domanda3=document.getElementById('domanda3');

    window.addEventListener('message',receiveMessage);
    function receiveMessage(e){
        if(e.origin!=="chrome-extension://ldjfmalmmomhpjmoeemlaingagdhagjl")
        return;
        domanda1.value = e.data.domanda1;
        domanda2.value = e.data.domanda2;
        domanda3.value = e.data.domanda3;
    }
}
```

**ps = thanks to wOxxOm for help**